# What did Moshe mean in Shemos 4:10?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, moshe-rabbeinu, parashas-shemos, shemot-exodus

Shemos 4:10 (Artscroll English Tanach)

"Moses replied to HASHEM, "Please, my Lord, I am not a man of words, not since yesterday, nor since the day before yesterday, nor since You first spoke to Your servant..."

Here Moshe was talking with G-d when He appeared to him in the Burning Bush. It was the first time God speak to Moshe according to the Torah.

Then what did Moshe Rabbeinu mean when he said "..nor since You first spoke to Your servant" ?

Answer (score 3):

Both Rash"i and Ramba"n citing Rash"i on [this verse](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14126&st=&pgnum=52) say that G-d was speaking to Moses for 7 days in total. The last reference, "since You first spoke to Your servant" refers to the very beginning when G-d first asked Moses to go to Pharaoh. Moses seems to refer to the 1st day.

Comment: Is this Miqraot Gedolot ?( I am a beginner in Judaism)

Comment: @mil It is. Normally, I would link to Sefaria.org, which should have the same commentary, possibly in English. My browser bars access to sefaria.

Answer (score 1):

According to R. Dovid Zvi Hoffmann on this posuk, *gam me'az deberkha* refers to the very beginning of this conversation.